# Jquery Progress Bar: Issue with implementing progress Bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, progress-bar, jquery-ui-progressbar

I'm having a problem with implementing the progress bar using the jquery UI progressbar widget. The actual bar in the widget is not loading in real time. It just jumps to the end bar when the timer is complete. I'm not sure to why its doing that. Any help is appreciated

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#start_timer").click(
        function () {
            var totalTime = $("#time").val();
            var interval = $("#interval").val();
            var isValid = true;

        $("#progressbar").progressbar({
                value:0
        });

        // validate the time
        if (totalTime == "") { 
            $("#time_error").text("This field is required.");
            isValid = false;
        } else if (isNaN(totalTime)) {
            $("#time_error").text("Time must be a number.");
            isValid = false;
        } else {
            $("#time_error").text("");
        } 

        // validate the interval
        if (interval == "") { 
            $("#interval_error").text("This field is required.");
            isValid = false;
        } else if (isNaN(interval)) {
            $("#interval_error").text("Interval must be a number.");
            isValid = false;
        } else {
            $("#interval_error").text("");
        }

        if (isValid) {
            totalTime = totalTime * 1000;
            interval = interval * 1000;
            var elapsedTime = 0;
            var displayMinutes = 0;
            var displaySeconds = 0;


            var timer = setInterval(
                function () {
                    elapsedTime += interval;
                    displaySeconds = elapsedTime / 1000;

                    $("#progressbar").progressbar("value", elapsedTime);

                    /*if (displaySeconds < 60) {
                        $("#elapsed").val(displaySeconds + " seconds");
                    } else {                                
                        displayMinutes = parseInt(displaySeconds / 60);
                        displaySeconds = displaySeconds % 60;
                        if (displaySeconds == 0) {
                            $("#elapsed").val(displayMinutes + " minutes");                                 
                        } else {
                            $("#elapsed").val(displayMinutes + " minutes " + displaySeconds + " seconds");                                  
                        }
                    }
                    if (elapsedTime == totalTime) {
                        clearInterval(timer);
                        $("#complete span").text("Time is up!")
                    }*/ 
                },
                interval );


        }
    }
);
$("#totalTime").focus();
```

});

Comment: Are you setting a progress bar maximum? Default is 100 according to docs [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/progressbar/)

Comment: No, I dont believe you have to define a max

Comment: Please provide the minimal HTML/CSS required to reproduce this or an online demo such as the inbuilt code snippet or jsfiddle. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)